# VST plug-in bridge for Mac OS X

Tags: plugins, mac, vst

I have some issues with some VST plug-ins and hosts (32/64 bit compatibility, OpenGL compatibility) on Mac OS X, therefore I'm looking for VST bridge solutions.

Are there any free or commercial VST plug-in bridges for Mac OS X, like jBridge for Windows?

Comment: Can you say more about what JBridge does, and which features you need?

Comment: jBridge hosts the plug-in in a separate process, for 32/64 bit compatibility between host and plug-in, among other benefits; hidden inter-process communication allows the total transparency of the usage of the plug-in.

Comment: I edited your question based on your comment (and you can do this too) - please edit further if I made any mistakes or incorrect assumptions!

Comment: Same question on Gearslutz: http://www.gearslutz.com/board/music-computers/583011-vst-bridge.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBridgeM (for Mac OS X) is out...

http://jstuff.wordpress.com/jbridgem/